# Azure WebJob-Project - access parent project artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am new to Azure WebJobs. For a mobile app we need some WebJobs that can run scheduled. My question is about the "Projects-Architecture" when it comes to WebJobs.

As far as i know, a new project is created for every WebJob. I am doing this by righclicking the main project -> add new azure webjob project.
But how are these projects "combined". There should be some reference to the parent project that i cannot find. I need to access the entities from the main project inside the WebJob. How should this be done?

Furthermore i am not sure wheter to implement Logic+Data access directly inside the WebJob or let the WebJob instead call another Controller to handle this?

Documentation on this is horrible, every help would be great.

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve via the web job? - this is important cause I am confused as to why you need to access the models of your web project here or there might be an alternative that I can suggest. And to answer your question about how does the web app / mobile app know that a web job exist - it does because when you deploy your web job you would do so by accessing your web app ->settings ->web jobs ->"upload your executables here" - this is the way i have done using the portal.

Comment: I want to request data from another service every day. That data should be saved into an sql database. We use Entity Framework Code First.
I think there is no way around referencing the project containing the entities?

Comment: We also came up with the question wether or not it is good practise to keep the entities-stuff in the Mobile App project? An extra Entity project would make sense as we wouldn't need to reference the stuff that we don't need.

Comment: Yes having the infrastructure (your domain models and EF repo code) project separately makes sense. So if I understand correctly, your web job needs to query some data from another source and use EF to insert them to your db - hope I got this one right. To do so I would say use your app's end point( or create a new one) to insert the data- this way you need not add those references again. Or if you are allowed -create this web job as a separate stand alone project-and allow it to accessing your db using the plain old ADO.net to push data into (this however is not reusing what you already have)

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new or existing WebJob Project to your solution, Visual Studio will take care of this for you. It is not something new, as if you are adding a console/windows service project to your web/MVC application.
If you need these projects to communicate, you till need to add references to your other projects just like you would in any other project which will in turn get compiled.

[image]

If you need to learn more and check some examples, this tutorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/ shows how to write code for a simple multi-tier ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses the WebJobs SDK. Maybe that can give you some information on how to architect the application.

Answer (score 0):

They are not really "combined".  There is a reference in the Web App (the webjobs-list.json) in properties that tells VS to publish the webjob when you publish the web app.  If you need to access entity models in the webjob, then you need to add a reference to your other projects just like you would in any other project (add the project reference and then add a using statement in the webjob).  The reference will get compiled into the webjob.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask what are you trying to achieve via the web job? this would help in identifying why the need for accessing the models of your MVC app.

One suggestion would be to push the object from the MVC app to an azure queue and then access it via your job. Set it up in a way to identify new messages in a queue. (trigger).  - not sure if this helps cause I am not sure how quick the web job is run and what are the other constraints you are working with.